# Mongoose not creating schema, or connecting to database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have been receiving an error whenever I "post" something using express and node. i can load the website, but it crashes once i submit my form data

This has been the result:

```
/Users/anishladdha/url_shortener/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/collection.js:185
          callback(new MongooseError(message));
                   ^

MongooseError: Operation `urls.findOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    at Timeout.<anonymous>
```

when i run this code:

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const request = require('request');
const https = require('https')
const { json } = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const shortID = require('shortid');
const URL = require("./models/url.js")

const app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

var mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost/url_short';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}).then(console.log("connected?"));
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
db.once("open", function() {
  console.log("MongoDB database connection established successfully");
});
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));


//app.get('/') works
app.post('/', async function(req, res) {
    let sid = shortID.generate
    await URL.create({
        longUrl: req.body.user_url,
        shortUrl: sid,
    });
    res.render('index', {sid: sid});
});
app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('listening on port:3000');
});
```

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: BTW, this is my schema:
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const urlSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        longUrl: {type: String, required: true,},
        shortUrl: { type: String, required: true,},
        clicks: {type: Number, required: true, default: 0,}
    },
    {timestamps: true});
module.exports = mongoose.model('URL', urlSchema);;

Answer (score 2):

OK, so this was quite possibly the stupidest thing i've ever done in my yers of coding.

I didnt realize you had to install mongodb for it to work :|

so yeah, probably do that

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/

Comment: hahaha! That's the best resolution I've seen so far. :)

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, almost every time the reason is two `mongoose` modules installed and used in a project. **You need to make sure there is only one `mongoose` in your `node_modules`.**

Type `npm ls mongoose` and find all the `mongoose` packages *which are not deduped*.

Example:

```
$ npm ls mongoose
my-project@1.0.0 /home/jon/code/my-project
├─┬ package-one@2.0.0
│ └── mongoose@5.11.18
├─┬ package-two@4.0.0
│ └── mongoose@5.12.2  deduped
└── mongoose@5.12.2
```

As you can see I have the `package-one` dependency which has its own (not deduped) copy of `mongoose` module.

There are various ways to solve it.

- Try changing (increasing / decreasing) your `mongoose` version.
- If you can, change the required `mongoose` version of your dependencies (package-one and package-two).

A good start would be to understand how [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org) works [in npm](https://docs.npmjs.com/about-semantic-versioning).

Comment: Thanks for the response!
└─┬ mongoose@5.12.2
  └─┬ mongoose-legacy-pluralize@1.0.2
    └── mongoose@5.12.2 deduped


it appears the only "duplicate" in deduped, so I dont think that thats the problem